# Uploading file of 80 mb getting this error Error: Bad compressed size: 0 != 350

Tags: javascript, angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkHra.png)

I'm encountering a stack overflow error in my code related to compression. I'm using [insert compression library/module] to compress data, but I'm receiving the following error message:

> "Error: Bad compressed size: 0 != 350".

Any insights on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated

`````js
   processXlsx(event: any): void {
     try {
     const target: DataTransfer = event.target;

     if (target.files.length !== 1) {
     throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
     }

      const file: File = target.files[0];
      const chunkSize =  1024 * 1024 // 1 MB chunk size (adjust as needed)
      const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      let offset = 0;

      // Add progress indicator for file upload
      reader.onprogress = (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
          const percentLoaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
         


if (percentLoaded === 100) {
        this.uploadbtn = true;
        this.uploading = false;
      }
      console.log('File upload progress:', percentLoaded, '%');
    }
  };`

 `reader.onload = (e: any) => {
    /* Read chunk of XLSX file */
  try{

  
    const binaryString:  ArrayBuffer = e?.target.result;
    // const range = { s: { r: 0, c: 0 }, e: { r: 19, c: 0 } }; // Define range for the first 20 rows (0-based index)
    // const options: any = { type: 'binary', range, bookType: 'xlsx' };
    // Process the chunk
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binaryString);
    console.log(workbook.SheetNames, "sheetnames");
    const worksheetName: any = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheetName];
  
    const data: any[] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });
    const rowsToProcess = data.slice(0, 20);
    console.log(rowsToProcess, "rows process")
    if (this.operatorType == 100007) {
      let index = -1;
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const innerArray = data[i];
        if (innerArray.includes('OPS ID')) {
          index = i;
          break;
        }
      }
  
      let headers: string[] = data[0];
      console.log(headers, "header")
      if (headers !== undefined) {
        headers = headers.map(header => header.replace(/\r/g, '').trim().replace(/^"|"$/g, ''));
        this.reconciliationColumnsEP = this.reconciliationColumnsEP.map(header => header.trim().replace(/^"|"$/g, ''));
        if (!this.compareHeaders(this.reconciliationColumnsEP, headers)) {
          this.showInvalidHeadersAlert();
        }
      } else {
        this.showInvalidHeadersAlert();
      }

    } else if (this.operatorType == 100008) {
      let index = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const innerArray = data[i];
    if (innerArray.includes('Instrument Number')) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  let headers: string[] = data[index];

  if (headers !== undefined) {
    headers = headers.map(header => header.replace(/\r/g, '').trim().replace(/^"|"$/g, ''));
    this.reconciliationColumnsJaaz = this.reconciliationColumnsJaaz.map(header => header.trim().replace(/^"|"$/g, ''));
    if (!this.compareHeaders(this.reconciliationColumnsJaaz, headers)) {
      this.showInvalidHeadersAlert();
    }
  } else {
    this.showInvalidHeadersAlert();
  }
    }
    // Move to the next chunk
    offset += chunkSize;
    if (offset < file.size) {
      const chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
    } else {
      // No more chunks to read, close the reader
      reader.abort();
    }
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
  };


  // Handle errors during file reading
  reader.onerror = (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
    console.error('File reading error:', e.target.error);
 
    
    // Handle error appropriately, e.g., show error message
  }
  
  // Read first chunk of file as ArrayBuffer
  const chunk = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
  }catch (error) {
    debugger;
    console.error('Error reading Excel file:', error);
    // Handle the error gracefully (e.g., display a message to the user)
  }
}````
`````

Comment: Ah, yes, good old insert compression library, a reliable classic.

Comment: Which is line 763?

Comment: I am not sure what is line 763 as there in so line numbers in stack overflow plz can anyone help me ? in this error?

Comment: If you don't know, how are we supposed to know? This is not a support forum. You have to make a minimal effort and not just dump code in here if you want our help - [ask]

Comment: so I have came to a solution that increasing chunk size to 20 MB that is 
 const chunkSize = 20 *  1024 * 1024 // 20 MB chunk size (adjust as needed)
 it will remove the error but the dom is still hanging due to large file